# Visual Studio 2017: TypeScript compile errors in node_modules

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

Trying to build an Angular app I am getting complie errors for typescript files in the node_modules folder.

For example:

> TS2420: Class 'CdkTable' incorrectly implements interface
>   'CollectionViewer'.

CdkTable is in @angular/cdk/typings/table/table.d.ts

Version of my tools:

npm -v: 5.0.3

node -v: v8.1.4

tsc -v: Version 2.2.3

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

Note that the project is compileable on other computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your `tsc` executable is the one installed via npm, and it is installed globally.

Check the version of the TypeScript SDK for Visual Studio that you have installed. It should be in a folder that is roughly: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`. Make sure this version is update-to-date (or at least at the same version as your globally installed TypeScript).

Also check your environment variables to see if there is a different version in your path. Visual Studio's MSBuild process uses the [MSBuild TypeScript tasks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/), which is going to grab TypeScript from the SDK install. This explains the difference in output from the command line (using the globally installed tsc) and the output from Visual Studio.

Additionally, there have been [known](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4161) [issues](http://movingfulcrum.com/visual-studios-bullshit-support-of-typescripts-tsconfig/) with using a tsconfig with a Visual Studio project. I know that it's supposed to be fully supported, but there are a lot of people that still report problems from what I've researched. It could be that you might want to drop the tsconfig in favor of using the TypeScript tab available when you right click on a project and select properties.

Alternately, you could try setting the `rootDir` compiler option in an attempt to single out the directory of the TypeScript files you actually need compiled. I know `excludes` should have prevented this, but again, Visual Studio might be hiccuping on the tsconfig in some way.

Comment: in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript" I had several version, I removed the newest - it was 2.4 now it is working

Comment: Yeah, 2.4 is way stricter. This has been causing a lot of people issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make sure my version of Microsoft.TypeScript.MsBuild matched the version of the 'typescript' devDependency in packages.json file ( in my case 4.6.3 ). After I downgraded the Microsoft.TypeScript.MsBuild assembly to the matching version, I right-clicked the "node_modules" folder it added and hit 'exclude from project'. Finally getting a reasonable amount of errors from TypeScript related to the source code I'm actually working on. Using react instead of angular, not sure if that makes a difference here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).